# Conditional Gradle dependencies based on function result

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, conditional-statements, cannot-find-symbol

How can i import Linphone library only when built in Sip Api is not supported?

Because this library greatly affects to apk size (~100 Mb)

This is example of conditional dependency (based on variable in gradle.properties) in my :app Gradle file:

```
if (project.hasProperty("usesip")
{
     implementation 'org.linphone:linphone-sdk-android:5.1.2'
}
```

This is my function (Java), that checks support of built in Sip Library:

```
public static boolean checksSupportSip(Context context)
{
    return SipManager.isApiSupported(context) && SipManager.isVoipSupported(context);
}
```

And i don't know, how can i fix 'cannot find symbol' error, when Linphone library is not imported, here:

```
import org.linphone.core.*;

public class LinphoneSIPTask extends SIPTask
{
    private Core core;//linphone core

    private final CoreListenerStub listener;//linphone events listener

    private RegistrationState registrationstate = null;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Do you want to import Linphone lib based on runtime `SipManager` check? Or to build two apks (with and without the lib) from the same code?

Comment: I want to remove LinPhone lib on runtime, when SipManager is supported

Comment: I know about two apks variant

Comment: Is it possible to add a library at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are distributing via Google Play, I think your only option is to use [Feature Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery#customize_delivery) with on-demand features. Move everything with Linphone library to a separate module and [request its installation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/feature-delivery/on-demand#request) after the app start.

Outside of Google Play is seems impossible.